# How to get rid of the __cft__[0] part of Facebook links in Chrome or FIrefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, facebook, tracking

I want to get rid of the `__cft__[0]`-part of internal Facebook links in my browser (Firefox or Chrome). The links work fine if you manually remove it, the cft-part is probably for tracking purposes (I guess that c=cookie and t=tracking. I think these cft-links started to appear when major browsers stopped supporting certain tracking cookies.).

**The purpose is to be able to distinguish between visited and unvisited links** (and of course minimize tracking). As far as I can tell, the cft-part of the link is dynamic and changes everytime you load a page.

**How can I get rid of the cft-part of internal Facebook links in Chrome and Firefox?**

Comment: https://github.com/Cimbali/CleanLinks/issues/125 means it is implemented in https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/clean-links-webext/

Comment: https://github.com/ClearURLs/Addon will probably also work https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clearurls/lckanjgmijmafbedllaakclkaicjfmnk & 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clearurls/

Comment: The link on your profile is dead btw.

Comment: @Gantendo What link?

Comment: https://superuser.com/users/177312/d-b   About

Do you like pop-corn? Upvotes on this Q&A is very appreciated https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/101197/how-do-you-make-popcorn-in-a-microwave-oven-using-normal-popcorn/

Comment: Edit it here: https://superuser.com/users/edit/177312 (scroll down a bit)

Comment: @Gantendo Some stupid moderator deleted the question. Ask at meta. The question is still there, just hidden.